# Can JMX work asynchronously and how performant is this technology?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jmx

I know that JMX technology allows to talk remotely among JVMs by making RPC call which is synchronous.

1. Can JMX work asynchronously (with some listeners as an example)?
2. Assume hundreds of agents make an RPC JMX call to the same function on a one JVM-process simultaneously. Would it be more performant to respond asynchronously by the JVM? Is it possible.
3. Has MBean server internally some ThreadPool (A thread per JMX-connection) for connection-management?